# Xcode is not letting the view to stay horizontally centered

Tags: ios, swift2, constraints, xcode-storyboard, ios-autolayout

ok i have this strange issue (cause i've never seen any error like this before) , i have a Textfield in my view and i'm expanding its width with animation from both sides (Trailing and leading)  but the problem is this its only expanding from one side (either trailing or leading)

my code :

**VIewController Class**

```
@IBOutlet var constraint1: NSLayoutConstraint! // textfield's leading constraint 
@IBOutlet var constraint2: NSLayoutConstraint! // textfield's trailing constraint 

    viewDidload(){........}

    @IBAction func editingBegin(sender: AnyObject) {

    fullnameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    fullnameTextField.clipsToBounds = false
    self.constraint2.constant = -16 // here i'm expanding the width by setting constant of my Textfield
    self.constraint1.constant = -16
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
        self.fullnameTextField.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

my NSlog error:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155e77fb0 UITextField:0x155d85e40.trailing == UIView:0x155e46800.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1546b02b0 UITextField:0x155d85e40.leading == UIView:0x155e46800.leadingMargin - 16>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1546447e0 UITextField:0x155d85e40.centerX == UIView:0x155e46800.centerX>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1546447e0 UITextField:0x155d85e40.centerX == UIView:0x155e46800.centerX>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

here's my Storyboard where i'm setting the constraints

[image]

the strange is that i'm doing the same thing on another View controller with and its working there but not here , i checked every constraint they are correct , and that NSLog error is also appearing in that ViewController(where the above is working fine )

anyone have any clue whats wrong here ? please let me know its so frustrating

code of my ViewController http://pastebin.com/BvfEvzPE

Comment: Your leading constraint should be only `16` while trailing would be `-16`.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara hey man your answer did the trick

Comment: thanks you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing AlignX constraint; Because You have already leading and tailing constraints so AlignX is not required.

You may download the sample code from here and compare it with yours;

http://www.filedropper.com/tst

Comment: thanks for responding man , been there done that , no changes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as @Shoaib said, remove the Center.x constraint. Either Center X + Width, or Leading + Trailing is enough.

But even so, the layout engine already breaks the Center.x constraint for you, and all should work as it is. However, judging by the log message, only the "leading" constraint has been modified (has a constant `-16`). The "trailing" one doesn't seem to be modified.
Make sure your IBOutlets are connected for both constraints.

**UPDATE**: actually, outlets should probably be fine, since it's Swift, and it would crash otherwise. I'd suggest going line by line through your code and looking at when the breaking constraints log message appears.

**UPDATE 2** (from comments): are you sure the order of views is correct in constraints? I mean, that depending on which view is the first and which is the second, you need to either set constant to +16 or -16. Try playing with +/-, since it's quicker than going to the storyboard and switching the views order. Maybe you should specify +16 for one of constraints.

Comment: thanks for responding ,  i checked it several times the connections are correct and i also tried by removing the centerX constraint still no changes

Comment: @remyboys, yes, sorry, I didn't think it through well enough. There's no way connections could be nil, because it's Swift. It would crash otherwise. See the update. I'll try to update my answer based on your further feedback.

Comment: please check my added whole code here http://pastebin.com/BvfEvzPE ,  i checked it by myself but didn't find any problem yet

Comment: @remyboys Two suggestions: first, make sure `constraint1` and `constraint2` aren't linked to the same constraint (the leading one). Second, try moving both `.constant = -16` inside the `animateWithDuration` block.

Comment: **aren't linked to the same constraint** i also thought this is it but thats not the case and i moved it inside that block still no change

Comment: @remyboys are you sure the order of views is correct in constraints? I mean, that depending on which view is the first and which is the second, you need to either set `constant` to +16 or -16. Try playing with +/-, since it's quicker than going to the storyboard and switching the views order. Maybe you should specify +16 for one of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the priority of CentreX constraint to 999

[image]

Click on **Edit** option and you can change the priority to 999

Hope it works!